# Can we use a specific algorithm to a particular queue in PBS

Tags: pbs, torque

I would like to use a specific algorithm to a particular queue. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't believe that its possible to do this although if it is it'd depend on what scheduler you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your scheduler and what algorithm you want to achieve. If you use Maui, there are some per-queue setting that you can tune.